# Magento 2 | VueJs Framework

Tags: magento2, javascript, framework, vuejs

Is there a way to use **VueJs Framework** under **Magento 2** ?

Comment: Check https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront

Comment: A very detailed answer is explained here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/310876/77

Answer (score 1):

Their is a way to integrate `VueJs` in you custom module.

You should do as follows:

1. Copy all content of this [url](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js) insaid you custom module

   > /Custom/Module/view/frontend/web/js/vue.js
2. Configure requirejs-config.js

   > /Custom/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js
   >
   > ```
   >     var config = {
   >        map: {
   >            '*': {
   >                vue: 'Custom_Module/js/vue'>             
   >            }
   >        } };
   > ```
3. And to use it:

   > ```
   > define([
   >     'jquery',
   >     'vue'
   > ], function ($, Vue) {
   >     "use strict";
   >     // code...
   > });
   > ```

Answer (score 0):

Vue js is a library/framework which needs to be included.  So include it and start writing some code in VueJS format.

This answer is a good summary.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/256234/70343

That's to use it.  It will not convert Magento 2.